Google Sheets App Script copyTo function stops working
I have found and adapted a script for google sheets for our timesheeting system that copies a template sheet to create a blank timesheet, whilst maintaining certain protections, to stop people breaking formulas.
In the spreadsheet there are a couple of other sheets, but the main thing is we keep running the script to add new sheets for each person. After exactly 4 additions, the script stops functioning completely, with the error:

Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id [insert doc ID code here]

Script below:
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('BLANK TIMESHEET'); 
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var p = protections[i];
    var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
      // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
   }
  }
  sheet2.activate();
}

To clarify, I also have these sheets in the workbook by default (in case sheet count is a factor for some reason:

Overview
Overtime report
Template (Hidden, this is the sheet that gets copied)
Settings (Hidden, just contains data validation stuff)

So to simply conclude, I have a timesheet template that gets duplicated on a button press per person. I can add 4 sheets to the doc and then the 5th gets the error code listed above.

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Related Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with ID xxx

I have tried a stripped back version of the spreadsheet and script in the aforementioned sheet maker and it appears to have no issue replicating endlessly, which is somewhat puzzling....
